# Dynamically changed view of XsltListViewWebPart (in the custom form)

Tags: custom-form, xslt-list-view-web-part, optimization

I have a form with custom XLV: `<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart ID="Xlv" runat="server" />`, AFAIK, the view for this webpart is stored in the list as hidden. When user open form, the XLV query is changed programmatically in form's code-behind class:

```
xmlDefinitionElement = XElement.Parse(view.HtmlSchemaXml);
// change XmlDefinition code
SubTaskListXlv.XmlDefinition = xmlDefinitionElement.ToString();
```

I have 2 questions:
1. Is there any conflict with the view when several users simultaneously open the form?
2. How can I initiate XLV with no/sample data, that it wouldn't request the server/db?

Comment: What version of SharePoint? How do you change the query? Please post more detail.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the details. It seems you are using code. You may want to elaborate on the details of that. Not all questions or answers here are about code, so if you use code and need a code solution, please make sure you explain your scenario *in toto* with all parameters involved.